# Comparing the proportion of men accessing a service to the proportion of men in the local population

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, chi-squared-test, proportion

I am looking at whether men access a service proportionally. My data is nominal and consists of men accessing a service (3000), woman accessing the service (6000), men in the local population (99300) and women in the local population (106600). I think that I would be using chi-square, due to the nominal nature of the data, and as I mentioned I want to compare the proportion of men - proportion of men accessing the service works out at roughly 34% and proportion of men in the local area works out at roughly 48%. I am using SPSS, however when I have tried using chi-square so I am getting a statistical significance of .000 which just does not seem right!
My questions are 1. is chi square the most appropriate test?
2. Would the large difference in numbers of men accessing the service and men in the local population be creating the large statistical significance? And if so, is there a way of comparing the proportions only?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The 0.000 result means that there's a massively significant difference, accounting for gender proportions in the overall population, for the number of men and women accessing the service.

In this case, that's correct: only about 1 in 33 men use the service compared to around 1 in 18 women.  The numbers being in the thousands, this is no fluke: it's a real effect.